# atop + what is the PAG in the atop

Tags: linux, rhel, atop

when I run the atop -r /var/log/atop/...

I see from the atop screen this

```
 PAG | scan  641376 |  steal 635209 | stall
```

the PAG is colored with red

can someone explain what PAG explain from the atop , and what this problem means ?

Answer (score 10):

man atop

> PAG  Paging frequency.
>   This line contains the number of scanned pages ('scan') due 
>   to the fact that free memory drops below a particular threshold 
>   and the number times that the kernel tries  to  reclaim  pages
>   due to an urgent need (`stall').
>
> Also the number of memory pages the system read from swap space ('swin')  > and the number of memory pages the system wrote to swap space ('swout') > are shown.

Basically, it (normally) indicates that your system is low on memory, which is not a good thing, hence it is in red.

Comment: so your suggestion is to increase the memory ?, and how to configure the memory pages ? according to what ?

Comment: > so your suggestion is to increase the memory ?

Well, probably, your original question was on what PAG is, so I've provided you with a description of it.

Comment: > and how to configure the memory pages ? according to what ?

You will normally just configure the total memory (and swap) limits, as pages are low level kernel thing, not something you have to reconfigure during the normal operation.

Comment: The first thing to check is an overall memory usage for your system, with the "free" command.

Comment: What does "steal" relate to? The atop man-page describes (cycle?) stealing in the context of virtual machines, but that does not seem to be what is shown under PAG.

Comment: @TimoReimann according to `sar(1)`
Number of pages the system has  reclaimed  from  cache  (pagecache  and
                     swapcache) per second to satisfy its memory demands.